# Python - download and convert .dat to .csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to download this file: `https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data`:

this:

```
18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1    "buick skylark 320"
18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1    "plymouth satellite"
16.0   8   304.0      150.0      3433.      12.0   70  1    "amc rebel sst"
17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1    "ford torino"
15.0   8   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70  1    "ford galaxie 500"
14.0   8   454.0      220.0      4354.       9.0   70  1    "chevrolet impala"
14.0   8   440.0      215.0      4312.       8.5   70  1    "plymouth fury iii"
14.0   8   455.0      225.0      4425.      10.0   70  1    "pontiac catalina"
15.0   8   390.0      190.0      3850.       8.5   70  1    "amc ambassador dpl"
15.0   8   383.0      170.0      3563.      10.0   70  1    "dodge challenger se"
14.0   8   340.0      160.0      3609.       8.0   70  1    "plymouth 'cuda 340"
15.0   8   400.0      150.0      3761.       9.5   70  1    "chevrolet monte carlo"
14.0   8   455.0      225.0      3086.      10.0   70  1    "buick estate wagon (sw)"
24.0   4   113.0      95.00      2372.      15.0   70  3    "toyota corona mark ii"
22.0   6   198.0      95.00      2833.      15.5   70  1    "plymouth duster"
18.0   6   199.0      97.00      2774.      15.5   70  1    "amc hornet"
21.0   6   200.0      85.00      2587.      16.0   70  1    "ford maverick"
27.0   4   97.00      88.00      2130.      14.5   70  3    "datsun pl510"
26.0   4   97.00      46.00      1835.      20.5   70  2    "volkswagen 1131 deluxe sedan"
25.0   4   110.0      87.00      2672.      17.5   70  2    "peugeot 504"
24.0   4   107.0      90.00      2430.      14.5   70  2    "audi 100 ls"
25.0   4   104.0      95.00      2375.      17.5   70  2    "saab 99e"
26.0   4   121.0      113.0      2234.      12.5   70  2    "bmw 2002"
21.0   6   199.0      90.00      2648.      15.0   70  1    "amc gremlin"
10.0   8   360.0      215.0      4615.      14.0   70  1    "ford f250"
10.0   8   307.0      200.0      4376.      15.0   70  1    "chevy c20"
11.0   8   318.0      210.0      4382.      13.5   70  1    "dodge d200"
9.0    8   304.0      193.0      4732.      18.5   70  1    "hi 1200d"
27.0   4   97.00      88.00      2130.      14.5   71  3    "datsun pl510"
28.0   4   140.0      90.00      2264.      15.5   71  1    "chevrolet vega 2300"
25.0   4   113.0      95.00      2228.      14.0   71  3    "toyota corona"
25.0   4   98.00      ?          2046.      19.0   71  1    "ford pinto"
19.0   6   232.0      100.0      2634.      13.0   71  1    "amc gremlin"
16.0   6   225.0      105.0      3439.      15.5   71  1    "plymouth satellite custom"
17.0   6   250.0      100.0      3329.      15.5   71  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
19.0   6   250.0      88.00      3302.      15.5   71  1    "ford torino 500"
18.0   6   232.0      100.0      3288.      15.5   71  1    "amc matador"
14.0   8   350.0      165.0      4209.      12.0   71  1    "chevrolet impala"
14.0   8   400.0      175.0      4464.      11.5   71  1    "pontiac catalina brougham"
14.0   8   351.0      153.0      4154.      13.5   71  1    "ford galaxie 500"
14.0   8   318.0      150.0      4096.      13.0   71  1    "plymouth fury iii"
12.0   8   383.0      180.0      4955.      11.5   71  1    "dodge monaco (sw)"
13.0   8   400.0      170.0      4746.      12.0   71  1    "ford country squire (sw)"
13.0   8   400.0      175.0      5140.      12.0   71  1    "pontiac safari (sw)"
18.0   6   258.0      110.0      2962.      13.5   71  1    "amc hornet sportabout (sw)"
22.0   4   140.0      72.00      2408.      19.0   71  1    "chevrolet vega (sw)"
19.0   6   250.0      100.0      3282.      15.0   71  1    "pontiac firebird"
18.0   6   250.0      88.00      3139.      14.5   71  1    "ford mustang"
23.0   4   122.0      86.00      2220.      14.0   71  1    "mercury capri 2000"
28.0   4   116.0      90.00      2123.      14.0   71  2    "opel 1900"
30.0   4   79.00      70.00      2074.      19.5   71  2    "peugeot 304"
30.0   4   88.00      76.00      2065.      14.5   71  2    "fiat 124b"
31.0   4   71.00      65.00      1773.      19.0   71  3    "toyota corolla 1200"
35.0   4   72.00      69.00      1613.      18.0   71  3    "datsun 1200"
27.0   4   97.00      60.00      1834.      19.0   71  2    "volkswagen model 111"
26.0   4   91.00      70.00      1955.      20.5   71  1    "plymouth cricket"
24.0   4   113.0      95.00      2278.      15.5   72  3    "toyota corona hardtop"
25.0   4   97.50      80.00      2126.      17.0   72  1    "dodge colt hardtop"
23.0   4   97.00      54.00      2254.      23.5   72  2    "volkswagen type 3"
20.0   4   140.0      90.00      2408.      19.5   72  1    "chevrolet vega"
21.0   4   122.0      86.00      2226.      16.5   72  1    "ford pinto runabout"
13.0   8   350.0      165.0      4274.      12.0   72  1    "chevrolet impala"
14.0   8   400.0      175.0      4385.      12.0   72  1    "pontiac catalina"
15.0   8   318.0      150.0      4135.      13.5   72  1    "plymouth fury iii"
14.0   8   351.0      153.0      4129.      13.0   72  1    "ford galaxie 500"
17.0   8   304.0      150.0      3672.      11.5   72  1    "amc ambassador sst"
11.0   8   429.0      208.0      4633.      11.0   72  1    "mercury marquis"
13.0   8   350.0      155.0      4502.      13.5   72  1    "buick lesabre custom"
12.0   8   350.0      160.0      4456.      13.5   72  1    "oldsmobile delta 88 royale"
13.0   8   400.0      190.0      4422.      12.5   72  1    "chrysler newport royal"
19.0   3   70.00      97.00      2330.      13.5   72  3    "mazda rx2 coupe"
15.0   8   304.0      150.0      3892.      12.5   72  1    "amc matador (sw)"
13.0   8   307.0      130.0      4098.      14.0   72  1    "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"
13.0   8   302.0      140.0      4294.      16.0   72  1    "ford gran torino (sw)"
14.0   8   318.0      150.0      4077.      14.0   72  1    "plymouth satellite custom (sw)"
18.0   4   121.0      112.0      2933.      14.5   72  2    "volvo 145e (sw)"
22.0   4   121.0      76.00      2511.      18.0   72  2    "volkswagen 411 (sw)"
21.0   4   120.0      87.00      2979.      19.5   72  2    "peugeot 504 (sw)"
26.0   4   96.00      69.00      2189.      18.0   72  2    "renault 12 (sw)"
22.0   4   122.0      86.00      2395.      16.0   72  1    "ford pinto (sw)"
28.0   4   97.00      92.00      2288.      17.0   72  3    "datsun 510 (sw)"
23.0   4   120.0      97.00      2506.      14.5   72  3    "toyouta corona mark ii (sw)"
28.0   4   98.00      80.00      2164.      15.0   72  1    "dodge colt (sw)"
27.0   4   97.00      88.00      2100.      16.5   72  3    "toyota corolla 1600 (sw)"
13.0   8   350.0      175.0      4100.      13.0   73  1    "buick century 350"
14.0   8   304.0      150.0      3672.      11.5   73  1    "amc matador"
13.0   8   350.0      145.0      3988.      13.0   73  1    "chevrolet malibu"
14.0   8   302.0      137.0      4042.      14.5   73  1    "ford gran torino"
15.0   8   318.0      150.0      3777.      12.5   73  1    "dodge coronet custom"
12.0   8   429.0      198.0      4952.      11.5   73  1    "mercury marquis brougham"
13.0   8   400.0      150.0      4464.      12.0   73  1    "chevrolet caprice classic"
13.0   8   351.0      158.0      4363.      13.0   73  1    "ford ltd"
14.0   8   318.0      150.0      4237.      14.5   73  1    "plymouth fury gran sedan"
13.0   8   440.0      215.0      4735.      11.0   73  1    "chrysler new yorker brougham"
12.0   8   455.0      225.0      4951.      11.0   73  1    "buick electra 225 custom"
13.0   8   360.0      175.0      3821.      11.0   73  1    "amc ambassador brougham"
18.0   6   225.0      105.0      3121.      16.5   73  1    "plymouth valiant"
16.0   6   250.0      100.0      3278.      18.0   73  1    "chevrolet nova custom"
18.0   6   232.0      100.0      2945.      16.0   73  1    "amc hornet"
18.0   6   250.0      88.00      3021.      16.5   73  1    "ford maverick"
23.0   6   198.0      95.00      2904.      16.0   73  1    "plymouth duster"
26.0   4   97.00      46.00      1950.      21.0   73  2    "volkswagen super beetle"
11.0   8   400.0      150.0      4997.      14.0   73  1    "chevrolet impala"
12.0   8   400.0      167.0      4906.      12.5   73  1    "ford country"
13.0   8   360.0      170.0      4654.      13.0   73  1    "plymouth custom suburb"
12.0   8   350.0      180.0      4499.      12.5   73  1    "oldsmobile vista cruiser"
18.0   6   232.0      100.0      2789.      15.0   73  1    "amc gremlin"
20.0   4   97.00      88.00      2279.      19.0   73  3    "toyota carina"
21.0   4   140.0      72.00      2401.      19.5   73  1    "chevrolet vega"
22.0   4   108.0      94.00      2379.      16.5   73  3    "datsun 610"
18.0   3   70.00      90.00      2124.      13.5   73  3    "maxda rx3"
19.0   4   122.0      85.00      2310.      18.5   73  1    "ford pinto"
21.0   6   155.0      107.0      2472.      14.0   73  1    "mercury capri v6"
26.0   4   98.00      90.00      2265.      15.5   73  2    "fiat 124 sport coupe"
15.0   8   350.0      145.0      4082.      13.0   73  1    "chevrolet monte carlo s"
16.0   8   400.0      230.0      4278.      9.50   73  1    "pontiac grand prix"
29.0   4   68.00      49.00      1867.      19.5   73  2    "fiat 128"
24.0   4   116.0      75.00      2158.      15.5   73  2    "opel manta"
20.0   4   114.0      91.00      2582.      14.0   73  2    "audi 100ls"
19.0   4   121.0      112.0      2868.      15.5   73  2    "volvo 144ea"
15.0   8   318.0      150.0      3399.      11.0   73  1    "dodge dart custom"
24.0   4   121.0      110.0      2660.      14.0   73  2    "saab 99le"
20.0   6   156.0      122.0      2807.      13.5   73  3    "toyota mark ii"
11.0   8   350.0      180.0      3664.      11.0   73  1    "oldsmobile omega"
20.0   6   198.0      95.00      3102.      16.5   74  1    "plymouth duster"
21.0   6   200.0      ?          2875.      17.0   74  1    "ford maverick"
19.0   6   232.0      100.0      2901.      16.0   74  1    "amc hornet"
15.0   6   250.0      100.0      3336.      17.0   74  1    "chevrolet nova"
31.0   4   79.00      67.00      1950.      19.0   74  3    "datsun b210"
26.0   4   122.0      80.00      2451.      16.5   74  1    "ford pinto"
32.0   4   71.00      65.00      1836.      21.0   74  3    "toyota corolla 1200"
25.0   4   140.0      75.00      2542.      17.0   74  1    "chevrolet vega"
16.0   6   250.0      100.0      3781.      17.0   74  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu classic"
16.0   6   258.0      110.0      3632.      18.0   74  1    "amc matador"
18.0   6   225.0      105.0      3613.      16.5   74  1    "plymouth satellite sebring"
16.0   8   302.0      140.0      4141.      14.0   74  1    "ford gran torino"
13.0   8   350.0      150.0      4699.      14.5   74  1    "buick century luxus (sw)"
14.0   8   318.0      150.0      4457.      13.5   74  1    "dodge coronet custom (sw)"
14.0   8   302.0      140.0      4638.      16.0   74  1    "ford gran torino (sw)"
14.0   8   304.0      150.0      4257.      15.5   74  1    "amc matador (sw)"
29.0   4   98.00      83.00      2219.      16.5   74  2    "audi fox"
26.0   4   79.00      67.00      1963.      15.5   74  2    "volkswagen dasher"
26.0   4   97.00      78.00      2300.      14.5   74  2    "opel manta"
31.0   4   76.00      52.00      1649.      16.5   74  3    "toyota corona"
32.0   4   83.00      61.00      2003.      19.0   74  3    "datsun 710"
28.0   4   90.00      75.00      2125.      14.5   74  1    "dodge colt"
24.0   4   90.00      75.00      2108.      15.5   74  2    "fiat 128"
26.0   4   116.0      75.00      2246.      14.0   74  2    "fiat 124 tc"
24.0   4   120.0      97.00      2489.      15.0   74  3    "honda civic"
26.0   4   108.0      93.00      2391.      15.5   74  3    "subaru"
31.0   4   79.00      67.00      2000.      16.0   74  2    "fiat x1.9"
19.0   6   225.0      95.00      3264.      16.0   75  1    "plymouth valiant custom"
18.0   6   250.0      105.0      3459.      16.0   75  1    "chevrolet nova"
15.0   6   250.0      72.00      3432.      21.0   75  1    "mercury monarch"
15.0   6   250.0      72.00      3158.      19.5   75  1    "ford maverick"
16.0   8   400.0      170.0      4668.      11.5   75  1    "pontiac catalina"
15.0   8   350.0      145.0      4440.      14.0   75  1    "chevrolet bel air"
16.0   8   318.0      150.0      4498.      14.5   75  1    "plymouth grand fury"
14.0   8   351.0      148.0      4657.      13.5   75  1    "ford ltd"
17.0   6   231.0      110.0      3907.      21.0   75  1    "buick century"
16.0   6   250.0      105.0      3897.      18.5   75  1    "chevroelt chevelle malibu"
15.0   6   258.0      110.0      3730.      19.0   75  1    "amc matador"
18.0   6   225.0      95.00      3785.      19.0   75  1    "plymouth fury"
21.0   6   231.0      110.0      3039.      15.0   75  1    "buick skyhawk"
20.0   8   262.0      110.0      3221.      13.5   75  1    "chevrolet monza 2+2"
13.0   8   302.0      129.0      3169.      12.0   75  1    "ford mustang ii"
29.0   4   97.00      75.00      2171.      16.0   75  3    "toyota corolla"
23.0   4   140.0      83.00      2639.      17.0   75  1    "ford pinto"
20.0   6   232.0      100.0      2914.      16.0   75  1    "amc gremlin"
23.0   4   140.0      78.00      2592.      18.5   75  1    "pontiac astro"
24.0   4   134.0      96.00      2702.      13.5   75  3    "toyota corona"
25.0   4   90.00      71.00      2223.      16.5   75  2    "volkswagen dasher"
24.0   4   119.0      97.00      2545.      17.0   75  3    "datsun 710"
18.0   6   171.0      97.00      2984.      14.5   75  1    "ford pinto"
29.0   4   90.00      70.00      1937.      14.0   75  2    "volkswagen rabbit"
19.0   6   232.0      90.00      3211.      17.0   75  1    "amc pacer"
23.0   4   115.0      95.00      2694.      15.0   75  2    "audi 100ls"
23.0   4   120.0      88.00      2957.      17.0   75  2    "peugeot 504"
22.0   4   121.0      98.00      2945.      14.5   75  2    "volvo 244dl"
25.0   4   121.0      115.0      2671.      13.5   75  2    "saab 99le"
33.0   4   91.00      53.00      1795.      17.5   75  3    "honda civic cvcc"
28.0   4   107.0      86.00      2464.      15.5   76  2    "fiat 131"
25.0   4   116.0      81.00      2220.      16.9   76  2    "opel 1900"
25.0   4   140.0      92.00      2572.      14.9   76  1    "capri ii"
26.0   4   98.00      79.00      2255.      17.7   76  1    "dodge colt"
27.0   4   101.0      83.00      2202.      15.3   76  2    "renault 12tl"
17.5   8   305.0      140.0      4215.      13.0   76  1    "chevrolet chevelle malibu classic"
16.0   8   318.0      150.0      4190.      13.0   76  1    "dodge coronet brougham"
15.5   8   304.0      120.0      3962.      13.9   76  1    "amc matador"
14.5   8   351.0      152.0      4215.      12.8   76  1    "ford gran torino"
22.0   6   225.0      100.0      3233.      15.4   76  1    "plymouth valiant"
22.0   6   250.0      105.0      3353.      14.5   76  1    "chevrolet nova"
24.0   6   200.0      81.00      3012.      17.6   76  1    "ford maverick"
22.5   6   232.0      90.00      3085.      17.6   76  1    "amc hornet"
29.0   4   85.00      52.00      2035.      22.2   76  1    "chevrolet chevette"
24.5   4   98.00      60.00      2164.      22.1   76  1    "chevrolet woody"
29.0   4   90.00      70.00      1937.      14.2   76  2    "vw rabbit"
33.0   4   91.00      53.00      1795.      17.4   76  3    "honda civic"
20.0   6   225.0      100.0      3651.      17.7   76  1    "dodge aspen se"
18.0   6   250.0      78.00      3574.      21.0   76  1    "ford granada ghia"
18.5   6   250.0      110.0      3645.      16.2   76  1    "pontiac ventura sj"
17.5   6   258.0      95.00      3193.      17.8   76  1    "amc pacer d/l"
29.5   4   97.00      71.00      1825.      12.2   76  2    "volkswagen rabbit"
32.0   4   85.00      70.00      1990.      17.0   76  3    "datsun b-210"
28.0   4   97.00      75.00      2155.      16.4   76  3    "toyota corolla"
26.5   4   140.0      72.00      2565.      13.6   76  1    "ford pinto"
20.0   4   130.0      102.0      3150.      15.7   76  2    "volvo 245"
13.0   8   318.0      150.0      3940.      13.2   76  1    "plymouth volare premier v8"
19.0   4   120.0      88.00      3270.      21.9   76  2    "peugeot 504"
19.0   6   156.0      108.0      2930.      15.5   76  3    "toyota mark ii"
16.5   6   168.0      120.0      3820.      16.7   76  2    "mercedes-benz 280s"
16.5   8   350.0      180.0      4380.      12.1   76  1    "cadillac seville"
13.0   8   350.0      145.0      4055.      12.0   76  1    "chevy c10"
13.0   8   302.0      130.0      3870.      15.0   76  1    "ford f108"
13.0   8   318.0      150.0      3755.      14.0   76  1    "dodge d100"
31.5   4   98.00      68.00      2045.      18.5   77  3    "honda accord cvcc"
30.0   4   111.0      80.00      2155.      14.8   77  1    "buick opel isuzu deluxe"
36.0   4   79.00      58.00      1825.      18.6   77  2    "renault 5 gtl"
25.5   4   122.0      96.00      2300.      15.5   77  1    "plymouth arrow gs"
33.5   4   85.00      70.00      1945.      16.8   77  3    "datsun f-10 hatchback"
17.5   8   305.0      145.0      3880.      12.5   77  1    "chevrolet caprice classic"
17.0   8   260.0      110.0      4060.      19.0   77  1    "oldsmobile cutlass supreme"
15.5   8   318.0      145.0      4140.      13.7   77  1    "dodge monaco brougham"
15.0   8   302.0      130.0      4295.      14.9   77  1    "mercury cougar brougham"
17.5   6   250.0      110.0      3520.      16.4   77  1    "chevrolet concours"
20.5   6   231.0      105.0      3425.      16.9   77  1    "buick skylark"
19.0   6   225.0      100.0      3630.      17.7   77  1    "plymouth volare custom"
18.5   6   250.0      98.00      3525.      19.0   77  1    "ford granada"
16.0   8   400.0      180.0      4220.      11.1   77  1    "pontiac grand prix lj"
15.5   8   350.0      170.0      4165.      11.4   77  1    "chevrolet monte carlo landau"
15.5   8   400.0      190.0      4325.      12.2   77  1    "chrysler cordoba"
16.0   8   351.0      149.0      4335.      14.5   77  1    "ford thunderbird"
29.0   4   97.00      78.00      1940.      14.5   77  2    "volkswagen rabbit custom"
24.5   4   151.0      88.00      2740.      16.0   77  1    "pontiac sunbird coupe"
26.0   4   97.00      75.00      2265.      18.2   77  3    "toyota corolla liftback"
25.5   4   140.0      89.00      2755.      15.8   77  1    "ford mustang ii 2+2"
30.5   4   98.00      63.00      2051.      17.0   77  1    "chevrolet chevette"
33.5   4   98.00      83.00      2075.      15.9   77  1    "dodge colt m/m"
30.0   4   97.00      67.00      1985.      16.4   77  3    "subaru dl"
30.5   4   97.00      78.00      2190.      14.1   77  2    "volkswagen dasher"
22.0   6   146.0      97.00      2815.      14.5   77  3    "datsun 810"
21.5   4   121.0      110.0      2600.      12.8   77  2    "bmw 320i"
21.5   3   80.00      110.0      2720.      13.5   77  3    "mazda rx-4"
43.1   4   90.00      48.00      1985.      21.5   78  2    "volkswagen rabbit custom diesel"
36.1   4   98.00      66.00      1800.      14.4   78  1    "ford fiesta"
32.8   4   78.00      52.00      1985.      19.4   78  3    "mazda glc deluxe"
39.4   4   85.00      70.00      2070.      18.6   78  3    "datsun b210 gx"
36.1   4   91.00      60.00      1800.      16.4   78  3    "honda civic cvcc"
19.9   8   260.0      110.0      3365.      15.5   78  1    "oldsmobile cutlass salon brougham"
19.4   8   318.0      140.0      3735.      13.2   78  1    "dodge diplomat"
20.2   8   302.0      139.0      3570.      12.8   78  1    "mercury monarch ghia"
19.2   6   231.0      105.0      3535.      19.2   78  1    "pontiac phoenix lj"
20.5   6   200.0      95.00      3155.      18.2   78  1    "chevrolet malibu"
20.2   6   200.0      85.00      2965.      15.8   78  1    "ford fairmont (auto)"
25.1   4   140.0      88.00      2720.      15.4   78  1    "ford fairmont (man)"
20.5   6   225.0      100.0      3430.      17.2   78  1    "plymouth volare"
19.4   6   232.0      90.00      3210.      17.2   78  1    "amc concord"
20.6   6   231.0      105.0      3380.      15.8   78  1    "buick century special"
20.8   6   200.0      85.00      3070.      16.7   78  1    "mercury zephyr"
18.6   6   225.0      110.0      3620.      18.7   78  1    "dodge aspen"
18.1   6   258.0      120.0      3410.      15.1   78  1    "amc concord d/l"
19.2   8   305.0      145.0      3425.      13.2   78  1    "chevrolet monte carlo landau"
17.7   6   231.0      165.0      3445.      13.4   78  1    "buick regal sport coupe (turbo)"
18.1   8   302.0      139.0      3205.      11.2   78  1    "ford futura"
17.5   8   318.0      140.0      4080.      13.7   78  1    "dodge magnum xe"
30.0   4   98.00      68.00      2155.      16.5   78  1    "chevrolet chevette"
27.5   4   134.0      95.00      2560.      14.2   78  3    "toyota corona"
27.2   4   119.0      97.00      2300.      14.7   78  3    "datsun 510"
30.9   4   105.0      75.00      2230.      14.5   78  1    "dodge omni"
21.1   4   134.0      95.00      2515.      14.8   78  3    "toyota celica gt liftback"
23.2   4   156.0      105.0      2745.      16.7   78  1    "plymouth sapporo"
23.8   4   151.0      85.00      2855.      17.6   78  1    "oldsmobile starfire sx"
23.9   4   119.0      97.00      2405.      14.9   78  3    "datsun 200-sx"
20.3   5   131.0      103.0      2830.      15.9   78  2    "audi 5000"
17.0   6   163.0      125.0      3140.      13.6   78  2    "volvo 264gl"
21.6   4   121.0      115.0      2795.      15.7   78  2    "saab 99gle"
16.2   6   163.0      133.0      3410.      15.8   78  2    "peugeot 604sl"
31.5   4   89.00      71.00      1990.      14.9   78  2    "volkswagen scirocco"
29.5   4   98.00      68.00      2135.      16.6   78  3    "honda accord lx"
21.5   6   231.0      115.0      3245.      15.4   79  1    "pontiac lemans
```

and convert it do `.csv`.

I read that `.dat` is already `.csv`, but when I try to use `pandas` in order to read the file, like:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
dataset = pd.read_csv(response)
```

it does not work, because original file it is not comma separated.

how do I convert it to `.csv`make it readable by `pandas` right away?

Comment: You do not need to convert it. Just read the docs for `read_csv` carefully and call it with the right parameters.

Comment: indeed. `dataset = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.data', sep='\s+')`did the job

Comment: Please click on given link "This question already has an answer here:...",
Where I post answer regarding your question and please upvote my answer if you get your answer.

Comment: @outkast. I wrote up an answer to the duplicate as well. While I targeted it for that particular question, I did add in a section for loading directly into a df. Let me know if it helps you.